# Where to put keystore file in Android?

Tags: android, ssl, keystore, android-keystore

I am currently working on a project that involves ssl communication. So, I want to copy my bks file to the device' s *internal* memory and access it afterwards. I am using a specific library for communication and I have to provide the bks file' s full path as a parameter to this library. Where should I put this bks file? Into the raw or assets folder or somewhere else? From which uri can I access this file? (In windows I am giving it C:\keys\blah.bks, so I have to give a similar uri like /data/data/com.example.exampleapplication/my_app/blah.bks or something like this.) How is this achieved in Android system?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in the `assets` folder of your app.

but consider encrypting it and letting your program decrypt it, since files in the assets folder are user accessible

Comment: Thank you :) Then, how can i refer to this file?

Comment: in Android you can use `file:///android_asset/blah.bks`

Comment: please note that all assets can be accessed by the user, if a key is supposed to be secret, dont store it on the device.